# Using Pumping Lemma to prove that $L=\{a^mb^{3m}:m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not recognizable over $A=\{a,b\}$

Tags: automata, formal-languages, finite-automata

[Pumping Lemma]: Let $\mathcal{A}=(Q,A,\cdot,i,T)$ be a (complete and deterministic) automaton and let $L=L(\mathcal{A})$ be the language recognized by $\mathcal{A}$. If $L$ is infinite and $\mathcal{A}$ is finite with $card(Q)=n$, given $w \in L$ such that $|w|=m \geq n$, there exist $u,v \in A^*$, $z \in A^+$ such that $|u|<n$, $|z| \leq n$ and $uz^pv \in L$ for all $p \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

> Prove that $L=\{a^mb^{3m}:m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not recognizable over the alphabet $A=\{a,b\}$.

Attempt: Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a deterministic and complete automaton with $n$ states that recognizes $L$.
Let $w \in L$ such that $|w|=l \geq n$.
Since $w \in L, w=a^mb^{3m}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$.
Then $l=m+3m=4m$.
By Pumping Lemma, there exist $u,v \in A^*, z \in A^+$ such that $w=uzv, |u|<n, |z|\leq n$ and $uz^pv \in L$ for all $p \in \mathbb{N}_0$.
What can I say next? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Take $m=2n$, so that $w=a^{2n}b^{6n}$. Then the lemma tells you that $w$ can be decomposed as $uzv$ in such a way that $|u|<n$, $|z|\le n$, and $uz^pv\in L$ for all $p\ge 0$. Notice that this implies that $|uz|<2n$, so $uz$ must be part of the string of $a$s in $w$. What happens now if you take $p\ne 1$? Is it actually still true that $uz^pv\in L$? In other words, does $uz^pv$ have exactly three times as many $b$s as $a$s?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you say to take $l=2n$ instead of $m$?

Comment: @Leafar: No, $\ell=|w|=2n+6n=8n$.

Comment: The point is that I can't choose $m$, but I can choose $l$, so if I choose $l=8n$ we clearly have $m=2n$

Comment: @Leafar: Of course you can choose $m$; whyever not? You’re simply choosing some member of $L$ that’s long enough (a) for the pumping lemma to apply and (b) to give you the desired contradiction.

Comment: Because $w=a^mb^{3m}$ for some $m$

Comment: @Leafar: And since every word of the form $a^kb^{3k}$ is in $L$, you can choose any one that you want. The trick is to choose one that does what you need it to do.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot, I tried with $p=0$ and nothing, but with $p=2$ I got it right

Comment: @Leafar: You're welcome. To see why $p=0$ also works, let $j=|u|$ and $k=|z|$. Then $u=a^j$ and $z=a^k$, so $v=a^{m-j-k}b^{3m}$, and therefore $$uz^pv=a^{j+kp+(m-j-k)}b^{3m} = a^{m+k(p-1)}b^{3m}\;.$$ This is in $L$ if and only if $3m=3\big(m+k(p-1)\big)$, i.e., if and only if $p=1$. If $p=0$, you have too few $a$'s for the $3m$ $b$s, and if $p>1$, you have too many.